# How do I make something I flash/blink more frequently as it gets closer to disappearing?

Tags: algorithm, rendering

In my game when you kill an enemy they may drop something like a health pack or gold.  I want this to have a time limit so that it eventually disappears if you don't pick it up.  I want the item to flash more frequently the closer the drop gets to "death".  How do you do the "more frequently flashing" algorithm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My concern with either of the approaches currently offered is that they'll both lead to 'variable-speed' blinking, which could not only be distracting for the players but also make it hard to gauge exactly how long an object has left before it vanishes.  Instead, somewhere in your parameters (whether they be global for the renderer or on a per-object basis) I would have four constants: `slowBlinkTime`, `slowBlinkRate`, `fastBlinkTime` and `fastBlinkRate`.  When rendering, if your object's remaining life is less than `fastBlinkTime`, then blink it at `fastBlinkRate`; otherwise if it's less than `slowBlinkTime`, then blink it at `slowBlinkRate`.  If you wanted to go a step further then you could have an array of distinct `blinkTime`s and `blinkRate`s and check them one by one, but in practice that's likely to be overkill and just having 'warning' and 'critical' states should be enough.  The code would look something like this:

```
float blinkCycle;
if ( entity.timeLeft < fastBlinkTime ) {
  blinkCycle = entity.timeLeft/fastBlinkRate;
} else if ( entity.timeLeft < slowBlinkTime ) {
  blinkCycle = entity.timeLeft/slowBlinkRate;
}
blinkCycle = blinkCycle - floor(blinkCycle); // find blinkCycle 'mod 1'
if ( (entity.timeLeft < slowBlinkTime) && (blinkCycle < 0.5f) ) {
  renderBlinked(entity); // this should be the 'blinked' state, whether flashed or missing
} else {
  renderNormal(entity); // the normal render for the entity
}
```

Note that this code presumes a half-on, half-off blink cycle (that's what the `0.5f` in the test represents), but could easily be tweaked for something like two-thirds on, one-third off just by tweaking the appropriate constant.  This also doesn't do anything to 'synchronize' blinking between the fast and slow states, but that's relatively straightforward to polish.

This should be straightforward to plug in, and it will have the IMHO substantial advantage that players will be able to see the switch from 'slow' to 'fast' blinking and know exactly how long they have left.  I would start with parameter values like 5s for `slowBlinkTime` and 0.5s for `slowBlinkRate`, and 2s / 0.25s for `fastBlinkTime` and `fastBlinkRate`, but that's definitely dependent on your particular game.

Comment: I don't understand.  If the blinking gets faster and faster, wouldn't that be a better gauge to exactly how long the object has left than just 2 modes?

Comment: @tieTYT The problem is that, especially when the rate of blinking is variable, it's hard for users to (a) determine exactly how fast an object is blinking, and (b) correlate that with how much longer it has to live.  Imagine having a slider from 0 to 100 vs. a 'switch' with positions at 0, 50, and 100; people may be able to guess at the value of the slider to within 5-10%, but they'll know exactly what value the switch is on - and it's much harder to gauge a rate than a position.

Comment: Despite what the votes suggest, I think this is the best answer.  In addition, it's way easier to implement (at least conceptually).  My answer got more votes, but I'm still not satisfied with it visually.  Your approach will give a satisfying look.

Answer (score 14):

If t goes down from T to 0, you could use something like sin((T - t)²) then if the number is > 0 you draw the object, if it's < 0 you don't

---

I've tried this out myself and I had to tinker with it. For me T was 100. This equation made things blink super fast the whole time. So to slow it down, I changed the equation to sin(((T - t)/10)²). This was after tinkering around with the numbers like /6 and /7.

I also tried this: sin((T - t)² * 1/100)

And then I didn't like how the drop seemed to be invisible almost as much as it was visible.  I wanted it to rarely be invisible.  I accomplished that by doing this: sin((T - t)² * 1/100) + .5  That + .5 shifts the sine "line" up so that it doesn't become < 0 as often.

None of this worked exactly the way I wanted.  The problem is that the blinking would start too soon.  I wanted the drop to be visible for 3 seconds and then start blinking.  To accomplish that, I did something like this:

```
isVisible(drop)
  if drop.t > x
    return true
  else
    sin((T - x - drop.t)² * 1/100) + .5 >= 0
```

That `x` would be the 3 seconds.

Also worth noting is that [this is the tool](https://www.desmos.com/calculator) I used the whole time to visualize how the blinking would look.  I think this would have taken 5x longer without the visual tool.

Comment: Awesome, I love this solution, Another quick way would be doing `sin(t * pow((t/T), 1.5))`

Answer (score 4):

Maybe with the help of another variable?

```lua
current_length = 4
length_decrease = 0.5
current_time = current_length

function update(delta_time)
    if current_time > 0 then
        draw()
    end
    current_time -= delta_time
    if current_time < -current_length then
        current_length -= length_decrease -- feel free to get creative here
        if current_length < 0 then
            disable_object()
        end
        current_time += current_length * 2
    end
end
```

It is a bit longer than the solution you proposed yourself, but you save yourself costly `sin` and `pow` operations, and you have much more control over how the blinking goes faster.